Is RAM bad when memtester reports errors but memtest86+ does not
I'm trying to troubleshoot my machine hangs/freezes, the machine is Intel i7-13700 CPU based with 64G RAM, running Debian 12.  I was running memtester with various memory sizes (up to 60G), it sometimes reports error even with the first test (Stuck Address).
However I also run memtest86+ for 12+ hours (8 passes) and it did not report any error.
The machine is still under warranty, should I ask for the RAM to be replaced based on these results?  Or could this be some Debian 12 / Linux kernel issue?
I upgraded Linux kernel to 6.7.x (from bookworm-backports), I did not get any hang for 1 day though the memtester still sometimes reports errors.

if warranty exists, ask the vendor for support

As djdomi says. In my experience, any indication of bad memory is a red flag. And different tests will test different aspects, so no matter which one shows the error, assume it's telling truth.

Thanks, my question really is - could this be not a hw/RAM problem, since memtest86+ does not report any error, it's only some Linux userspace program (memtester) that reports it.  I think the vendor won't run Linux to test the memory when I return the machine.  But I guess I don't have any other option.

since my CPU is apparently affected by the recent Intel CPU instability issue, I wonder if it could contribute to this problem
